# How do I convert a English phrasing of a number(string) to integer in Python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, integer

Write a Python program that takes an English phrasing of a `number` as a string `s` and outputs
the corresponding integer `x`. You can assume the `number` is positive and less than `1,000,000`. You can also
assume that the `s` is always correct. `s` does not contain any spaces.

So far, I have my dictionary

```
'# ones

num2words =        {'one': '1', 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4, 'five':5, 'six':6, 'seven':'7', 'eight':8, 'nine':9}

'# tens

num2words.update  ({'ten':10, 'eleven':11, 'twelve':12, 'thirteen':13, 'fourteen':14, 'fifteen':15, 'sixteen':16,
'seventeen':17, 'eighteen':18, 'nineteen':19})

'# twenty-ninety

num2words.update  ({'twenty':'20', 'thirty': '30', 'fourty':40, 'fifty':50, 'sixty':60, 'seventy':70, 'eighty':80,
'ninety':90})

'# hundred, thousand, million, zero

num2words.update  ({'hundred':'100', 'thousand':1000, 'million':1000000, 'zero':0})
```

and I don't know how to get started with writing this program. I've looked up examples, but the strings usually have a space or dash separating them for example (twenty-seven or twenty seven) instead of (twentyseven or onehundredfiftysixthousandthreehundredtwentyseven) just some guidance in how to start my program would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

not sure whether helps: maybe using regex to search whether key matches?
then twenty-seven and 'twenty seven' would match key twentyseven

```
import re

txt = "twenty seven"
txt = "twenty-seven"
x = re.search("twenty.*seven", txt)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This module `https://pypi.org/project/word2number/` can help you. It turns words into digits and back.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like two separate tasks
a)the splitting of the given string
and
b) afterwards generating the number from a)'s result.

a) Here you should probably check which of your dictionary keys the string begins with, then repeat the same procedure with the leftover string until you are finished. The string method `startswith` will be helpful for this.
But be aware of some pitfalls like fourty or sixty, where also four and six would match. These cases need be handled in addition. Maybe with a rule like

'whenever there are several matches, take the largest one.'

(You have to check whether this is true for all options.)

b) Here try to translate into code how you would process the number string yourself. Mostly its additions except if you find powers of 10 like hundred, thousand, or million. This will lead to a multiplication with the sum of what is left of the found power of ten.